# Eclipse Jess plugin not working

Tags: eclipse, jess

I have a rather strange problem with Eclipse Jess plugin. Everything seems to be installed correctly, plugin details say I have Jess, Jess Debugger and Jess Editor Plug-in and clp files are syntax highlighted and given the jess logo icon in the path manager.

When I try to run even the Hello World example it refuses to launch saying that it refers a non-existing project

(the test-java project I've made just to see that jdk is installed correctly).
Also noice the filename is not shown in the upper bar, next to TestJava.java, there is a tab that only holds the close symbol.

EDIT - I wanted to put screenshot here, but my rep is too low, so I will describe it here:
I have a test-java project which is a pure java project I used to test if JDK is installed correctly. Below I have the jess project which is just a generic project with a src directory and test.clp file inside.
When I try to open the clp file I get a null pointer exception, but when I write it anew, the text does get syntax highlighting. In the upper bar the filename is not showing, the tab for the clp file only has the 'x' symbol as though the name of the file was lost somewhere on the way.
There is also an error message I got when trying to launch the jess project (jess run section IS present in run config menu)

```
Problem Occured

Launching New_configuration has encountered a problem.

Launch Configuration New_configuration references a non-existing project test-jess
```

I have tested jess in the terminal and both JESS_HOME(jess root directory) and JESS($JESS_HOME/bin) are set, jess starts, commands execute.

I am running Xubuntu 14.04 Eclipse Juno 32 bit, oracle java 32 bit. I've tried Kepler with same results, and Luna does not work at all with Jess plugin.

Finally, when I try to make any operation with the clp file (move, rename, anything that involves the clp extension) I get a Null pointer exception, so it seems like the plugin is perhaps incompatible?

Comment: Tried it with Luna on Linux/Ubuntu. The Jess icon is in place, but only one plugin (gov.sandia.jess) shows up. A .clp source file isn't marked with "Jo" and there's no syntax highlighting.

Comment: I know it doesn't work with Luna, but this is not the issue here. The problem I have is it does not work with ANY version of eclipse. I got everything to show up correctly in both Kepler and Juno, but both get this null pointer exception when I try to do anything related to the clp file. Like the name was not loaded by eclipse/plugin - as stated, even the title bar does not show up the file name but only the close button

Comment: It was only meant as an independent confirmation. I guess you need the source to look into this one, which I haven't.

Comment: did anybody have any problems with this plugin under linux or did someone **get it to run on linux? **

Comment: Although most of these issues are mystifying to me, it does sound as though you're trying to run Jess programs from a non-Java project, and that's not supported. You must store your Jess code in Java projects, not plain Eclipse projects.

Comment: I have made an empty java project via new->java project menu entry - the clp file is given the jess icon, however it has the symptoms described in the original post.The clp file is under /src directory in the project (where I'd expect the java packages to appear)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot with this same issue.

The simple solution to this when you create a new project make sure it is a JAVA project and not a simple project. The launch configurations don't work for a simple project in eclipse.